# Add ENS domain name to a smart contract?

Tags: contract-deployment, etherscan, ens

Is it possible to add a ENS domain (like project.eth) to a deployed smart contract ?

If yes, is it compatible with Metamask and Web3js ?

Answer (score 0):

It's usual that projects would give their multisig wallet contract an ENS domain. You could assign one account as the registrant/controller (account with rights to control the ENS domain settings, usually an EOA), and another account to be the ETH record (the address the ENS domain routes to on Ethereum). As far as Metamask knows, an ENS domain is simply an alias to an Ethereum address. Doesn't matter if it's an EOA or a contract address.